# How to integrate ionic 2 with Django

Tags: django, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've worked with Django for web apps but now i have to implement it in my mobile application that is use django as the backend for my application.
Can anyone please suggest how to integrate django with ionic 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create an api for your app to consume the back-end data. 
You can use Django-rest-framework: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [ionic with Django backend](http://www.aptuz.com/blog/mobile-apps-using-angularjs-django-djangorestframework-and-redis-part-1/) and [Django Rest Backend](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)